# Stall torque for servo

Tags: servo, torque

My understanding of stall torque is that it's the amount of torque produced by the servo when the output is stationary. Suppose the stall torque of a servo was 10kg-cm. It can lift the a 10kg load at 0.9cm but not at 1.1cm. But does it mean it'll actually drop the load at any distance greater than 1cm? That is, it'll drop the load at distances 1.1cm, 1.2cm, 2cm, etc.?

Comment: Think the other way around - stall torque is the torque required to hold the servo in position. Anything greater than that will either hold it in position as well, or will reverse it, depending on gearing.

Comment: Nobody can say what happens. The servo could have a worm-wheel inside which prevents 'dropping' a load. Also the specs are often approximated and, depending on the country and seller, over or under estimated.

Comment: In theory that is what it means as long as you are in Earth gravity since motors don't apply a mass, they apply a force. At long lever arms, it will not be able to apply a force at the end of the lever in that can completely counter gravity, only partially counter it. Similar to how you can slow how quickly something lowers even though you might not be strong enough to actually lift it up.

Comment: There is no difference whether you change the arm length or the weight itself. So, in addition to having or not locking-type gearing inside, as @Oldfart commented above, think what happens to the servo mechanically if you put say 100kg weight at 0.5cm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But does it mean it'll actually drop the load at any distance greater
>   than 1cm? That is, it'll drop the load at distances 1.1cm, 1.2cm, 2cm,
>   etc.?

Generally yes, assuming the stall (holding) torque specification is accurate.

A servo with worm gearing may be able to hold its position even with no power. However even a worm drive can slip if enough force is applied. If the gearing supports a certain holding torque unpowered then it should support even more holding torque when powered (assuming it doesn't jump teeth or break).

Another definition of stall torque is the load that *causes* it to stall. In this case at higher torque the servo may continue holding its position, or it may be pulled off until the positional error drives the motor harder (typical behavior of 'analog' hobby servos), or it may 'drop' the load until torque reduces, or it may shut down and move freely due to detecting an overload (behavior of some 'digital' hobby servos).

Note that the torque specifications of 'hobby' servos are often 'optimistic', and may even burn the servo out if an attempt is made to operate it at rated torque.